# How can I use OR clause in GQL for app engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I am writing an web application using Google app engine. I am new to app engine so no idea how can we write down below query.I want to get unique record from my table.

Here is query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERMASTER WHERE username='larry' OR emailID='abc@abc.com' AND accounttype='USER_LOGIN';
```

But getting Invalid GQL query string.

Please help me to make it correct so I can fetch unique records.

Answer (score 0):

**From [GQL Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference):**

> **GQL does not have an OR operator. However, it does have an IN
>   operator, which provides a limited form of OR.**
>
> The IN operator compares value of a property to each item in a list.
>   The IN operator is equivalent to many = queries, one for each value,
>   that are ORed together. An entity whose value for the given property
>   equals any of the values in the list can be returned for the query.